Convert shader displacement to geometry in blender 4.2.3 to 3d print
Convert shader displacement to geometry in blender 4.2.3 to 3d print.
I have several equations I want to fit in different size shapes (This example is in a mesh circle)
How can convert the shader displacement equation into geometry?
Geometry nodes setup

Shader nodes setup with example equation

Image:

Image:

Blend file.


You substitute the texture coordinates and mapping with a Position node.
And the displacement by a set_position node, where the offset input will be a vector math multiplying normal_node * sine (for the circle, just a combine of 0,0,sine will be enough, but for shapes that face other ways, you will need the normal)
Scales will be wildly different, since shaders use a mapping from 0 to 1 and geometry nodes will use the real position of the vertices. So you will also need to adjust your multipliers.
In the image below, your equations will be inside the Displacement_Math area. You can basically use the exact same nodes you used in shading.



(In the last case, the "noise" needed to be 3d)

Thanks for the help but, some of the instructions didn't work
"And the displacement by a set_position node, where the offset input will be a vector math multiplying normal_node * sine (for the circle, just a combine of 0,0,sine"
A quick image would help a lot.

@Still, done...

This setup only seems to only work for noise displacement but not for converting shader displacement into geometry.

@RickT, the question has the shader displacement calculated with nodes, just use the same nodes in geometry instead. There is an area in the answer highlighted exactly to put the displacement nodes inside. (The question is: how can I convert the shader displacement "equation" in geometry)

If the shader can't be reproduced you can still bake color to texture and use that.

@DanielMöller  I've tried your nodes setup and it doesn't seem to convert shaders to geometry at least with the current setup.  "Convert shader displacement to geometry"

@MarkusvonBroady I tried baking using the baking node but it looks like a couple of steps need to be added.

@Still, it's not "bake node", it's bake texture. Then you will need to put that baked (saved image) texture replacing the noise is in my suggested setup. The hand work is similar to the handwork you need to convert the shader displacement "equation" to geometry nodes, but I think it will be harder to do than just replicating the nodes (unless you're used to baking already)

Many shader nodes can be copy/pasted into geometry nodes.
